# Change in Binary without change in Source Code

Tags: unix, binary, timestamp, elf

I have the following requirement: To Find if my binary has changed or not.

My source code is unchanged. When I recompile the binary (without change in Source Code), I notice that the Binary is changed. Not in Size, but in Contents.

On debugging a little, I found there is something called "Link Time" inside the binary file. This is the actual timestamp when the binary was linked. Now since each compile will give different timestamps, hence my binary contents are always different. But actually it should be the same.

Can somebody suggest me a way of finding out if the binary has actually changed due to change in source code, and not anything else.

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you need this?

Comment: Hi Emil, i need it coz my build server is triggered whenever I have updated any source code and checked it in subversion. It checks-out all the source codes, compiles them and then I need to check-in only the modified binaries back into subversion. But I am unable to find the binary which is actually modified. Subversion shows me that all the binaries are updated coz of this link time.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike on Windows (where every .obj file has a compile timestamp in its file header), UNIX object files, and in particular `ELF` files do *not* encode any kind of timestamp.

However, if your source uses `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` macros, then the object file produced by compilation will obviously change.  Also, all kinds of information, including compilation timestamp could be recorded as part of the debug info, if you are building `-g` binaries.

Finally, it's possible that the linker you are using does record the link timestamp (as a vendor extension).

Your fist task should be to *understand* where the differences from one build to the next come from.

If from `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, eliminate them from your source.

If from debug info, compare the binaries after passing them through `strip -g`.

If from vendor linker extension, see if there is a flag to disable such timestamps. If there isn't one, you'll have to write a tool that compares only the parts you are interested in. E.g. you could use `readelf -x.text a.out`, etc. to compare only the `.text` section (you'll also want to compare `.data`, `.rodata`, and likely many others).

Comment: bravo, Excellent diagnosis and hypothesis generation! Good luck to all.